# How to get the robocopy(or other cmd program) output in a WINForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd

I have a GUI program, which would call a cmd in this GUI program. In my case, the GUI call the robocopy to copy the file to a file server.And I want to show the progress in the GUI. So how can I get the output of the robocopy and display it on my GUI.

Best Regards,
Yongwei Xing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`StandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) stream:

```
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

// ...
// read from process.StandardOutput
```

Alternatively, rather than reading from `StandardOutput` directly, you can call [`BeginOutputReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx) passing a callback that will tell you whenever a new line is outputted.